# Need intuitive scanning software... done with FOSS

Tags: software-recommendation, scanner, xsane

OK, been using XSane for many years now, it has not evolved in as many. I need something that is intuitive, say for something as simple as being able to adjust the scan size for multipage documents from a sheet feeder. Maybe even de-skewing features, as some android apps do. Whenever I do a google search for a suitable replacement, nothing really comes up. So I'm tempted to assume I am the only person in the world with such requirements, but maybe not. Suggestions? At this point, FOSS is not a requirement, but Microsoft or Apple are not an option.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! What’s your Ubuntu version and what’s your scanner model? Since your question looks for a [tag:software-recommendation], you should also read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) from [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive